# Will the Bourbon Tunnel in Naples be open for visitors on September 19?

Tags: italy, naples

According to [Galleria Borbonica](http://www.galleriaborbonica.com/en/tours/standard) tours of the Bourbon Tunnel can be done on "*Fridays, Saturdays, Sundays and on holidays*". My question is...  will September 19 be a holiday that they'll be open? According to the [Bank Holiidays in Naples](http://www.officeholidays.com/countries/italy/index.php) September 19 is a holiday in Naples (Feast of St Gennaro).

The Bourbon Tunnel has three types of tours:

- Standard
- Adventure
- Speleo

The latter two require reservations whereas the first one does not. But the URL to book tours in English doesn't work. The "Reserve your tour" button on the [Adventure Tour](http://www.galleriaborbonica.com/en/tours/adventure/) takes you to [Adventure Reservation](http://www.galleriaborbonica.com/en/reservation/adventure) gives an "**error 404**".

The Italian language link, however, does work: [Prenota la tua visita](http://www.galleriaborbonica.com/it/prenota/avventura).

But it only goes up to September 3!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I traded Facebook messages (in Italian) with [Galleria Borbonica](https://www.facebook.com/GalleriaBorbonica/): they have not yet decided whether to be opon on the 19th of September, the Festival of San Gennaro. This year it falls on a Tuesday, and might open only the Bolla for viewing the aquaduct bridges. The decision will be taken at the end of August, with a 70 percent chance of being open on the 19th.

> Salve..non abbiamo ancora deciso..sarebbe un festivo locale..poiché è martedi potremmo decidere di essere aperti x il ponte però decideremo a fine agosto..probabilità di apertura 70 x cento!!!

They are VERY responsive, within an hour, so you might FB message to check just before your trip, or when you're already in Italy.